# tomcat 7: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm writing a full-stack web application using SpringMVC and Tomcat.  When I run the program, it seems to work fine, no error messages, nothing in the log.  But in Postman, all I'm getting is "The requested resource is not available."   Here's my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="JspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: just curious: what do you mean with "full-stack" web application?

Comment: I mean it takes full advantage of Spring's Model-View-Controller stack.

Comment: just to let you: that's not really how the term is meant to be used. Also, unfortunately, it is unlikely you'll get a satisfactory answer on this question, because it is pretty hard to judge why you would get this problem just by looking at these two xml files (that look fine to me). I can suggest setting up your project using Spring Boot, as it makes setting up a Spring MVC/Tomcat project a lot easier and less error prone.

Comment: It was a learning experience to do it myself.  Also, the web app is designed to grow if necessary, it's not just a simple web app.

Answer (score 0):

If working with Eclipse try Project>Clean... and then right click your tomcat server, in "Servers" view and click "Clean..."

Comment: Ok, tried it, but still getting the same error message.